# Replace one model attribute by another in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, attributes

I am building a very simple movie review app with Rails, which does not have any authentication system.

The app has:

- a User model (id, name, email), which has many Reviews and has many Comments
- a Review model (id, title, image, content), which belongs to one User and has many Comments
- a Comment model (id, content), which belongs to one User and belongs to one Review

Here is the _form.html.erb file for comments:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :review_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When adding/editing a comment, the user can chose the Review to which the comment will be attributed, thanks to:

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.number_field :review_id %>
</div>
```

which lets him chose between review ids.

Instead, I would like the user to be able to select the review title of the review he wants to comment upon.

I tried to modify the review model with a to_param method, but it did not solve the problem and actually created some other bugs in the app.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to `ply`'s answer, what you have to remember is when you populate an object-based form, you're really taking a `Model`'s attributes & populating them

[`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

> Typically, a form designed to create or update a resource reflects the
>   identity of the resource in several ways: (i) the url that the form is
>   sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a
>   request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the
>   appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource), (ii)
>   input fields should be named in such a way that in the controller
>   their values appear in the appropriate places within the params hash,
>   and (iii) for an existing record, when the form is initially
>   displayed, input fields corresponding to attributes of the resource
>   should show the current values of those attributes.

--

You are populating the `Comment` model object - this will have attributes defined in your database, such as `body`, `title` etc

One of the attributes in the `Comment` model is the `review_id` [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

To the `Comment` model, it does not matter *how* `review_id` is passed to it; just that it's done. This is why it does not matter if you use a `text_field` to input the id directly, or if you use a `select` tag to help the user select the item they want

--

**[collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)**

```
<%= f.collection_select(:review_id, Review.all,
                  :id, :title,
                 {:prompt => 'Please select the review of this comment'}) %>
```

This will give you a select box where you can pick the `review`

--

[**Nested Route**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

A *much* better way to do this is to use a nested route, so you can set `review_id` from the parmas:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reviews do
   resources :comments #-> /reviews/1/comments/new
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   @comment.save
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content).merge(review_id: params[:review_id])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rich: both approached you suggest solved my "problem".

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I follow, but could you just use a select tag here?

This assumes you have an instance variable named @reviews defined in your controller that will be available.
In this case @reviews could be something like Review.all

```
select_tag "review", options_from_collection_for_select(@reviews, "id", "title"), prompt: "Select a review"
```